# selection attribute in Ember.select not working within a loop

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have select view within a loop, and I wanted to set the default selection on the drop down. I tried setting "value" attribute as well as "selection" attribute but nothing worked for me. I was trying to create jsbin to demonstrate the issue, but then it is giving me completely different issue which I don't see in my dev code though.

My controller is defined like :

```
App.AnswerController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
        answerLayouts: function () {
            return this.get('store').findAll('layout');
        }.property(),
        selectedAnswerLayout: null,
        initialize: function () {
            this.set('selectedAnswerLayout', this.get('store').find('layout', this.get('id')));
        }.on('init')
    });
```

and in the template I am doing:

```
<table>
    {{#each answers itemController="answer"}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{name}}</td>
        <td>{{view Ember.Select
            content=answerLayouts
            optionValuePath="content.name"
            optionLabelPath="content.displayName"
            class="form-control"
            prompt="Answer Layout"
            selection=selectedAnswerLayout}}
        </td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
</table>
```

and does't see answerLayouts as an array, but when I check {{answerLayouts.length}} it returns 3!

Here is a jsbin link that demonstrates the issue: http://jsbin.com/AcUPIpEl/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok had to do things bit differently to get things working. Rather than defining "answerLayouts" as a property, I defined it as an array and when the controller gets initialized, I populated the array and set the selectedAnswerlayout there like this:

```
App.AnswerController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
        answerLayouts: Ember.A(),
        selectedAnswerLayout: null,
        initialize: function () {
          var self = this,
              selectedlayoutId = this.get('id');
        this.get('store').find('layout').then(function(data){
          data.forEach(function(layout){
            self.get('answerLayouts').pushObject(layout);
            if(layout.get('id') === selectedlayoutId){
               self.set('selectedAnswerLayout',layout);
            }
          });
        });


        }.on('init')
    });
```

Here is the working jsbin link : emberjs.jsbin.com/ODaKIjIw/3. 
I have realized that when we can define things in init, it's best to do so there. I have had issues with bindings when relying on computed property before. Lesson learned :)

Answer (score 1):

It's an issue with the old version of Ember, it was fixed somewhere between 1.0+ and 1.2

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ODaKIjIw/1/edit

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the jsbin with the latest ember version like you did and the selects are not rendering here: http://jsbin.com/AcUPIpEl/5/. But I can't still get the default selection thing to work(Layout 1 should have been selected by default for 2 drop downs). PS. like the new hat :)

Comment: I think I had defined the relation wrong in the model. I think I have fixed the relation here http://jsbin.com/AcUPIpEl/6/, using DS.belongsTo